# How to download the exact source code of the webpage

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsoup

I want to download the source code of the webpage. I have used URL method i.e URL url=new URL("http://a.html");

and Jsoup method but not getting the exact data as mentioned in actual source code . for example-

```
<input type="image"
       name="ctl00$dtlAlbums$ctl00$imbAlbumImage"    
       id="ctl00_dtlAlbums_ctl00_imbAlbumImage"
       title="Independence Day Celebr..."
       border="0"         
       onmouseover="AlbumImageSlideShow('ctl00_dtlAlbums_ctl00_imbAlbumImage','ctl00_dtlAlbums_ctl00_hdThumbnails','0','Uploads/imagegallary/135/Thumbnails/IMG_3206.JPG','Uploads/imagegallary/135/Thumbnails/');"
       onmouseout="AlbumImageSlideShow('ctl00_dtlAlbums_ctl00_imbAlbumImage','ctl00_dtlAlbums_ctl00_hdThumbnails','1','Uploads/imagegallary/135/Thumbnails/IMG_3206.JPG','Uploads/imagegallary/135/Thumbnails/');" 
       src="Uploads/imagegallary/135/Thumbnails/IMG_3206.JPG"     
       alt="Independence Day Celebr..." 
       style="height:79px;width:148px;border-width:0px;"
/>
```

In this tag the last attribute 'style' is not detecting by the code of jsoup. and if I am downloading it from URL method, It changes the style tag into border=""/> attribute.

Can any body tell me the way to download the exact source code of a webpage?
My code is-

```
URL url=new URL("http://www.apcob.org/");
InputStream is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
File fileDir = new File(contextpath+"\\extractedtxt.txt");
Writer fw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
 // System.out.println("line\n "+line);
  fw.write("\n"+line);
}
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(contextpath+"extractedtxt.txt";));
String baseUrl="http://www.apcob.org/";
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(in,"UTF-8",baseUrl);
System.out.println(doc);
```

Second method I followed is-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url_of_currentpage).get();
```

I want to do this in java and the website name is 'http://www.apcob.org/' on which this problem is occurred.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably due to a different `user agent` string - when you browse the page from your browser, it sends a `user agent` string with the browser's type. Some sites respond with different pages to different browsers (eg. mobile devices).
Try to add the same `user agent` string as your browser's.

Answer (score 2):

The page you're trying to download is modified somehow by a javascript code.
Jsoup is an html parser. It doesn't run javascript.

If you want to get the source code like you can see it in Chrome, use one of the following tool:

- [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j)
- [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)
- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

All three can parse and run the Javascript code inside the page.

Comment: no i have used jsoup (mentioned in my question) but not getting the same data. example i have mentioned in my question

Comment: @anny An important part was missing in the question. I highlighted it and changed my answer in consequence. Please see my update.

Comment: ohk ,, but my complete code depends on jsoup so i can't change my parser now. According to my research jsoup is better than htmlunit parser as i can't update the data in it

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would work fine,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Only If you're using a proxy
    //System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    URL url = new URL("http://www.apcob.org/");

    HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but it's not working as i wanted(explained in question)

Comment: @anny I've updated my answer. Now I'm using HttpUrlConnection (and not UrlConnection) and added the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy function to fetch webpage. Get the HTML String using this. Then parse the `String` to `Document` using `JSOUP`.

```
public static String fetchPage(String urlFullAddress) throws IOException {
//      String proxy = "10.3.100.207";
//      int port = 8080;
        URL url = new URL(urlFullAddress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
//      Proxy proxyConnect = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxy, port));
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//proxyConnect);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10')");
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000); // set timeout

        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        connection.addRequestProperty("connection", "keep-alive");
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String urlString = "";
        String current;
        while ((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
            urlString += current;
        }

        return urlString;   
}
```

If the problem turns out to be with JSOUP Parser, try using http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html. It parses HTML as-is, without correcting errors.

Few other things I noticed:
You did not close `fw`. Replace `UTF8` with UTF-8`.
If you need to parse a lot of CSS, try a CSS-Parser

Comment: if i am including user agent then for this website  http://www.apcob.org/ the content is not completely downloading. but if i am not including user agent then http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/ this website is not downloading. i am using chrome browser. I added connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");

Comment: my chrome version is Version 49.0.2623.28 beta-m.

Comment: oh sorry ..i got my mistake .. i was not writing fw.close(); thats why it was not reading completely. thank you so much for this nice answer

Answer (score 0):

When getting a webpage via `http`, the web server usually formats the sorce in some way; you can't get the exact sorce of a `php` file using `http`. 
As far as I know, the only way to accomplish what you are asking is by using `ftp`.

Comment: why are you talking about a php file in your answer..? I'm not sure OP wants to download the uncompiled source code of a website

Comment: @ibiza the OP is said they are looking for "the way to download the exact source code of a webpage", and I am pretty sure "exact source code" is the same as "uncompiled source code".